# Create data frames sampling randomly based on conditions at 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, random, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe A with 10,000,000 rows and 5 columns like this one:

```
SNP REC AF X Y Z
rs1 2.3 0.22 sss ff 472
rs200 4.7 0.7 d tg 634
rs33 30.1 0.5 ddf ap 929
```

Using R, I'd like to generate 50 new data frames with all columns from A, looping through the first 50 rows in the following way.

For each i,j in columns REC,AF, choose 1000 random rows from A (sampling with replacement) where the following 2 conditions are met:

```
1) i-2.5 < i < i+2.5 # i = value in REC
2) j-0.05 < j < j+0.05 # j = value in AF
```

**For instance; for row 1: choose 1000 random rows in A where REC ranges between -0.2 and 4.8, and where AF ranges between 0.17 and 0.27; for row 2: choose 1000 random rows in A where REC ranges between 2.2 and 7.2, and where AF ranges between 0.65 and 0.75; ... for row 50: ...; etc**

I know how to use the sample function:

```
A[sample(nrow(A), 1000,replace = TRUE), ]
```

But I don't know how to automate the function.

Any suggestion will be highly welcome !

Comment: Not clear. `i` is for every value in `REC` ? Can you show first few rows of expected daatframe?

Comment: Hi @RonakShah. Yes, i is for every value in REC (loop through first 50 rows of A, but sampling rows from the whole A which meet the 2 conditions). Please see EDIT. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` here. Subset `REC` and `AF` for only first 50 values, find out indices which are in range and `sample` 1000 rows which match the criteria.

```
Map(function(i, j) df[sample(which(df$REC > (i - 2.5)  &  df$REC < (i + 2.5) &
           df$AF > (j - 0.05)  &  df$AF < (j + 0.05)), 1000, replace = TRUE), ],
      df$REC[1:50], df$AF[1:50])
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Ronak Shah !. May I ask how you extract the 50 data frames from that function?

Comment: @Lucas store the output of that function in an object. Say `lst`. So do `lst <- Map(function(i, j) df...........`. Now you can use `lst[[1]]`, `lst[[2]]` to extract individual dataframes.